# Некорректно работает метод onProgressUpdate

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Есть метод `doInBackground`, который в цикле скачивает `json` файл по ссылке, разбирает его и передаёт информацию в метод `onProgressUpdate`. `onProgressUpdate` получает информацию и выводит её в `table row`. На эмуляторе и, при подключенном реальном устройстве, всё работает правильно, но если отключить реальное устройство от ПК, то некоторые `table rows` не заполняются. Никак не могу понять в чём может быть проблема. Извиняюсь что код получился большим, но если выложить не полностью, то трудно будет определить проблему.

```
     public String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Количество строк- "+ tl.getChildCount());
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "----------Старт BackGround-----------");
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            String resultJson = null;
            BufferedReader reader;            
            try {
                count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < tl.getChildCount() ; i++) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Старт цикла номер - " + i);               
                    numb = i;

                    URL url = new URL(adress);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 400 || urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 404) {

                        inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
                    } else {
                        inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    }

                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(line);
                    }
                    resultJson = buffer.toString();

                    dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(resultJson);
                    if(dataJsonObj.has("object") && !dataJsonObj.isNull("object")) {
                        JSONObject object= dataJsonObj.getJSONObject("object");
                        String object = object.getString("true");
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "object- " + true);
                        publishProgress(true);

                    }

                    else {  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ссылка " + adress);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "false");
                        publishProgress("false");
                    }
                    dataJsonObj.remove(resultJson);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Конец цикла - " + i);
                    buffer.setLength(0);
                    inputStream.close();
                    reader.close();
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
  return resultJson;
        }



 protected void onProgressUpdate(String... strings) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(strings);
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    TableRow tr = (TableRow) tl.getChildAt(numb);
    TextView textView = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(1);
    textView.setText(string);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Проверка onProgressUpdate");
    }
```

P.S. надеюсь кто-то сможет прочесть мой код, пытался подписать все непонятные моменты. Заранее благодарен за любые советы и пинки в правильное направление..
**UPDATE:** На реальном устройстве иногда правильно работает, иногда нет. Это не зависит от получаемой информации в json объекте, т.к. информация всегда одного типа и примерно одного размера. Может быть причиной проблемы плохое соединение с интернетом, т.е. UI не успевает изменится и начинается уже новый цикл? Если да, то как это пофиксить? может таймаут какой-то назначить для ожидания полного скачивания-передачи?

Comment: код вы как-то покромсали, я не уверен, что он в таком виде вообще компилируется. Из проблем, у вас есть гонка на `numb`. Я не эксперт в андроиде, но думаю, что `publishProgress` не ждет, пока отработает соответствующий `onProgressUpdate` и цикл может увеличить `numb` до того, как UI-thread достанет по нему `TableRow` (если вообще увидит изменение). Лучше передавать номер строки вместе с содержимым (через `publishProgress(numb, "false")` или отдельным объектом).

Comment: @zRrr я немного обновил вопрос, но мне кажется это никак не влияет, т.к. иногда все работает правильно, а иногда происходит "перескок". Тем более на эмуляторе все всегда правильно работает. Если я ошибаюсь, поправьте меня пожалуйста, я новичок в этом деле.. Хотя, я попробую Ваш совет, может я не правильно вижу работу приложения..